# assignment value is not updated immediately in if block after minification

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I have code similar to following. in if statement i am doing the math operation as well as assigning to the lastChangedTime variable, this code works fine without minification, but after minification, even though it goes in if statement, the lastChangedTime is having value assigned by timeDiff. why is this happening.

```
var getLastUpdatedDurration = function (timeDiff) {
                 var lastChangedTime = timeDiff;

                 if ((lastChangedTime = Math.round(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365))) > 0) {
                     lastChangedTime > 1 ? lastChangedTime += " years" : lastChangedTime += " year";
                 } 

                 return lastChangedTime;
             };
```

simplified minification code for this function looks like shown below. from the following code i was expecting to return 10 years. as after dividing value is assigned to t but it returns 100 which was initially assigned. can someone tell me whats wrong with following code.

```
      var v = function (n) {
  var i = 100,
    t = i;
  return t + ((t = Math.round(i / 10)) > 0 ? " years" : (t = Math.round(i / 10)) > 0 ? " seconds" : " milliseconds")
}
```

Comment: are you assigning in side if conditional or you were checking ==.  It looks like you need to use ==

Comment: There's a lot of extra code in the minified code